# Counting single occurrences of text based on text of another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

My spreadsheet currently looks like this :

[image: Current Spreadsheet]

The formula I am using to calculate 'occurrences' is :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SIGN(COUNTIF(OFFSET(B$2:$C$2,ROW(A1:A9)-1,0),"*")))
```

The formula is counting 'FIRST' only once per row  - the result of 4 is what I want.

However, what I have been struggling to do is to do the same calculation but this time based on the text 'POINTER'.

I.E I would have the same result but it would calculate based on the text being on the same row as 'POINTER'.

I have tried to use another countif loop to filter out the POINTER text but it returned 0. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: it is not counting `FIRST` is is counting non-Blank Cells, which just happens to coincide with FIRST.

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(SIGN(COUNTIF(OFFSET(A$2:$C$2,ROW(A1:A9)-1,0),"POINTER")))`

Comment: Sure. My larger spreadsheet will have lots of variations of text so I do want it to count non-blank cells. Just used 'FIRST' as a example for the purpose of the question.

Comment: But that formula does not consider any specific text, only that the cells be non blank.  If you want to consider specific text then the `"*"` must be changed to the specific text and the range `B$2:$C$2` increased to include all column in which you want to look.

Comment: Actually, apologies. Now I ACTUALLY understand what you meant.  I changed the formula to: =SUMPRODUCT(SIGN(COUNTIF(OFFSET(B$1:$C$9,ROW(A1:A9)-1,0),"POINTER"))) , to try and increase the range but it is now returning 0.

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(SIGN(COUNTIF(OFFSET(A$2:$C$2,ROW(A1:A9)-1,0),"POINTER")))`  You need to include Column A.  There is no `POINTER` in the other columns so it will not find anything.

Comment: Right yes, that is correct. If I include column A, it then counts the number of times that POINTER is present, if I understand? However, what I am trying to do is count text in columns B and C(only count once even if text is present in both) IF POINTER is in column A. So for example, if I typed in FIRST in cell B5 in the example above I would not want that counted as it does not have POINTER in cell A5. Hope that makes sense, managed to confuse myself a little with this one.

Comment: AHHHHH: `=SUMPRODUCT(SIGN(COUNTIF(OFFSET(B$2:$C$2,ROW(A1:A9)-1,0),"*"))*($A$1:$A$9="POINTER"))`

Comment: I would've thought this is what is actually required - given you're looking for 'FIRST' not 'any non blank' - this was apparently understood but I'm not quite sure anything came of it... hmmmmm (?).  `=SUMPRODUCT(SIGN(COUNTIF(OFFSET(B$2:$C$2,ROW(A1:A9)-1,0),"FIRST"))*($A$1:$A$9="POINTER"))`

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot(s) refer.

Desc: count unique occurrences of 'a' provided 'x' in col A

```
=SUM(--IF(A2:A16="x",(COUNTIFS(OFFSET($B$2:$E$2,SEQUENCE(ROWS(B2:B16),1,0,1),0),"a")>0)),)
```

[image: Data, eqns + checs]

---

*Note: replace sequence with row(..) - 1 if you do not have Office 365 compatible version of Excel.*

Comment: Darn - only seeing 'hidden' comments now - looks like soln already found - albeit this is somewhat different - I prob prefer the one in the comment. (except for the fact that it uses `sumproduct` which should have been deprecated by now, and the fact that its still counting any non-blank (?)